# I want to execute this script every minute and send me a message every time it changes state

Tags: python, time, notifications

I am working on a raspberrypi, I want to put this code in crontab to be exectuted every minute, it should low the gpio from 19:00 to 19:minute_max (and this part works) then it should send me an email when it changes the state of the GPIO. I'm able to send me an email when its set to LOW. Whit this code:

```py
from time import localtime
import  RPi.GPIO as  GPIO

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(26, GPIO.OUT)

ore = 19
minuti_max=30
minuti = range(0,minuti_max)

if (localtime()[3]==ore) and (localtime()[4] in minuti):
    if GPIO.input(26)==1:
        GPIO.output(26, GPIO.LOW)
        #send_mail_to_me("ON","yeye")
        print("on")
else:
    GPIO.output(26, GPIO.HIGH)
```

If I put a send_mail_to_me function in the else statement it will send me it every minute. But I want that it is send only when it set the gpio high for the first time.

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```py
from time import localtime
import  RPi.GPIO as  GPIO

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(26, GPIO.OUT)

ore = 19
minuti_max=30
minuti = range(0,minuti_max)

if (localtime()[3]==ore) and (localtime()[4] in minuti):
    if GPIO.input(26)==1:
        GPIO.output(26, GPIO.LOW)
        #send_mail_to_me("ON","yeye")
        print("on")
        flag=1
elif (localtime()[4] not in minuti) and flag==1:
    GPIO.output(26, GPIO.HIGH)
    #send_mail_to_me("OFF","yoyo")
    print("off")
    flag=0
else:
    GPIO.output(26, GPIO.HIGH)
```